# Convert rows, columns and values in data frame into 3 distinct columns in R

Tags: r

I have the following

rows names for df (AA, AB, AC)

df$12(WT, WT, MUT)

df$34(WT, WT, MUT)

df$56(MUT, WT, WT)

```
     12   34  56
AA   WT   WT  MUT
AB   WT   WT  WT
AC   MUT  MUT WT
```

I would like to get the following df2

df2$GS(AA, AB, AC, AA, AB, AC, AA, AB, AC)

df2$SI(12, 12, 12, 34, 34, 34, 56, 56, 56)

df2$NT(WT, WT, MUT, WT, WT, MUT, MUT, WT, WT)

```
     GS   SI  NT
     AA   12  WT
     AB   12  WT
     AC   12  MUT
     AA   34  WT
     AB   34  WT
     AC   34  MUT
     AA   56  MUT
     AB   56  WT
     AC   56  WT
```

My current code so far is

```
setDT(df, keep.rownames = TRUE)[]
```

But after that I am a bit lost on the next set of code to generate df2.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a `data.table` instead of a `data.frame`? Do you need a `data.table` solution?

Comment: Assuming you want to use data.table try this: `library(data.table); DT <- as.data.table(df, keep.rownames = "GS");
M <- melt(DT, id = "GS", value.name = "NT", variable.name = "SI");
M[, SI:=as.integer(as.character(SI))]`

Comment: Or with base R:  `df3 <- setNames(as.data.frame.table(as.matrix(df)), c("GS", "SI", "NT"));
df3$SI <- as.integer(as.character(df3$SI))`

Comment: data.frame is preferred, but data. table would work.  Your suggestions worked.  Thank you!